# Node Express server works in Heroku staging pipeline but not on production pipeline (no such app error)

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I developed an api with nodejs, express and run (npm start) with pm2 ([link](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/)). I published the app on heroku in a pipeline, I use the staging and production pipeline. The staging app works fine, but the production app is very inconsistent, succeeding sometimes and failing most.

Below the api access log, in the second request there is an error 404 with "no such app" in the html body error message (it is not in the image log).

```
2021-11-22T12:52:37.266486+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting server in port  12080
2021-11-22T12:52:37.567394+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/token" host={hidden}-production.herokuapp.com request_id={hidden} fwd="{hidden}" dyno=web.1ect=0ms service=692ms status=200 bytes=613 protocol=https
2021-11-22T12:53:12.688593+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/token" host={hidden}-production.herokuapp.com request_id={hidden} fwd="{hidden}" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=35ms status=404 bytes=711 protocol=https
```

I believe it is not a route problem, it works sometimes and in staging it works fine. I'm using Heroku's promotion button (staging -> production).
Is there a problem with Heroku?
Are any different configurations required for the application in production?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my app syncing with the Heroku routers.
Was fixed by the Heroku team itself.